Using Wordpress has_shortcode to detect do_shortcode
I have a template file where I am using do_shortcode() to execute a short code.
In the template file I have:
<html>
...
<?php do_shortcode( '[my_shortcode]' ); ?>
...
</html>

I have used the following code in my functions:
function my_function() {
 if ( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my_shortcode' ) ) {
    //do stuff here (i.e. load stylesheet for shortcode content)
 }
}

If I am not mistaken, $post->post_content (or the get_the_content() function) return only the post/page content, not the template. How do I get the entire content into has_shortcode?

you can load the stylesheet for shortcode content in beginning of the template file.

@mmm Thank you for the response, but it does not answer my question, though it does brush on why I want to detect the use of do_shortcode in the template file. If the template is not using the short code via do_shortcode, then I do not want the scripts/styles to enqueue.

in the template you can use the same conditions to enqueue files and to call the shortcode. you can even enqueue theses files in the shortcode itself, and files will be added in the footer of the html code.

@mmm Either my question is not clear or I am not understanding your answer. I am developing a plugin. Presumably I am not going to know if someone using the plugin has utilized do_shortocode in a template file to use the provided shortcode. I attempted to add the add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts) inside the shortcode callback; I pressume this will not work as by the time do_shortcode has been called, WP is no longer checking for script/style actions. If I am wrong, please provide an answer (not comment) with sample code so I can better understand. Thank you.

@mmm Nevermind! I figured it out. Your comment led me to do another search: can wp_enqueue_style/script be used inside a shortcode callback. The answer is: Yes.

Thanks to comments from @mmm, I figured out (or found) the answer to my question.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/enqueue-scripts-and-styles-via-shortcode/
Basically, you can call wp_enqueue_style or wp_enqueue_script within the callback for the shortcode itself.
<?php

add_shortcode( 'shortcode' , 'shortcode_callback' );

function shortcode_callback() {

     wp_enqueue_style( 'style-slug' , 'path-to-stylesheet.css' );

     $output = ...html here...

     return $output;

}

So whether your shortcode is called within a post/page or by using do_shortcode() in a template file, any stylesheet or script file your shortcode needs will be enqueued, but only if the shortcode is used.
